# ¿Con qué puedo sustituir el evento "onkeypress" en Chrome y Firefox?

Tags: javascript

Por lo visto el keypress ya no se puede utilizar en Chrome y Firefox.

¿Alguien sabe con que substituirlo?

Este es mi código:

```js
    function enterfrm()
    {
        
        codeName = navigator.userAgent;
        if (codeName.indexOf("Firefox")>-1 && codeName.indexOf("Chrome")>-1) {
            if (){
                frmLogin.submit();
            } else{
        
                if(window.event.keyCode==13){
                    frmLogin.submit();
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deberías usar el evento `keydown` pero no sólo en **Chrome** y **Firefox**, si no en todos los navegadores.

El evento `keypress` está "[deprecado](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress)" y, aunque funciona en muchos casos para mantener la compatibilidad con desarrollos antiguos, no debería utilizarse en nuevos desarrollos. A la vez que se debería ir quitando de los antiguos para evitar que dé problemas en las futuras versiones de navegadores.

```js
function enterfrm(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 13){
    console.log('Enter pulsado');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', enterfrm);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me funciona!!!